# SceneKit SCNTransaction time

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm looking for a simple way to make my SCNTransaction time-dependent, like in this example:

```
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
textNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0.0, y: 10* "myTime"^2 , z:0.0)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Where do I find the "myTime"-property running from 0 to 1 (or from 0 to animationDuration)? I wonder why I'm to blind to see it..

This would be so much nicer than hooking up everything into a CADisplayLink. Thank you!